# In SQL, how to calculate standard deviation with a row excluded from the calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a number of rows, which have `ID`, 'Group' and `Value` columns. I'd like to calculate the standard deviation on `Value` column for each of the `Group`. In the calculation, I have to exclude each of the record in the group out and carry out the calculation, then assign the result to the row. How can I achieve it?

Many thanks.

EDIT: I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

EDIT2:

Suppose we have a table

```
ID    Group    Value
1       A       2.5
2       A       4.1
3       B       3.8
4       B       11.2
5       B       15.4
6       C       0.8
7       C       7.1
8       C       1.0
9       B       5.2
10      A       6.9
```

The expected output is

```
ID    Group    Value     Std(pseudo values)
1       A       2.5       xxx
2       A       4.1       xxx
3       B       3.8       xxx
4       B       11.2      xxx
5       B       15.4      xxx
6       C       0.8       xxx
7       C       7.1       xxx
8       C       1.0       xxx
9       B       5.2       xxx
10      A       6.9       xxx
```

The calculation of standard deviation of certain group is assigned to individual rows in `Std` column. But in order to assure the independence, we do it as `std_x1 = STD(x2, x3, x4, ...)`.

Comment: The answer likely depends on your database engine which you failed to specify.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What do you mean by `I have to exclude each of the record in the group out and carry out the calculation, then assign the result to the row`?

Comment: Sample input & expected output please

Answer (score 1):

To count STD based on assupmtion `std_x1 = STD(x2, x3, x4, ...)` and `std_x2 = STD(x3, x4, x5, ...)` you can use this query:

```
SELECT  t.ID, 
        t.[Group], 
        t.Value,
        STDEV(t.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY [GROUP] ORDER BY t.ID ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS std
FROM    tbl t
```

To count STD based on assupmtion `std_x1 = STD(x2, x3, x4, ...)` and `std_x2 = STD(x1, x3, x4, x5, ...)` you can use this query:

```
SELECT  t.ID, 
        t.[Group], 
        t.Value,
        (SELECT STDEV(t1.value)
         FROM   tbl t1      
         WHERE t1.[Group] = t.[Group]
         AND t1.ID <> t.ID) AS Std
FROM    tbl t
```

Comment: Hi, Rafal. Thanks for the answer, it is awesome. However, the `std` in my question is simplified for the answerers to understand the question easily. In fact, the `std` is a weighted std, so it can be extract as `SQRT[sum(Vi - mean)*exp(Wi)/(N*exp(Wi))]`, so there are aggregate functions included in the code. I am wondering if the above answer can also work in this scenario? Many thanks.

Comment: BTW, my case is based on the second assumption.

Comment: I think this sollution could be used in your scenario. If you provide your formula with informations what Vi, meam, Wi i'll try to write this query for you.